# Is this code calling a constructor that doesn't exist?

Tags: c++

Perhaps this is a basic misunderstanding, but the following line is confusing to me:

```
return *static_cast<MockBehavior*>(COMPOSITE::m_Children[index]);
```

What exactly is this line doing?

Comment: How on earth am I supposed to know what this line is doing having no idea what COMPOSITE:: is, what the member m_Children is, what index is, whether there are any #define macros that may be overriding any of these tokens...?

Comment: @djechlin other people seemed to cope perfectly well.

Comment: No, without knowing, what the return type is and what all the identifiers are nobody can really tell what's happening. Especially the question about c'tors depends on this knowledge.

Comment: @djechlin other people seemed to cope perfectly well.

Answer (score 3):

Your title and question text seem inconsistent, but the line takes the pointer notated by `COMPOSITE::m_Children[index]` (where COMPOSITE should be some sort of namespace or class), casts the pointer type to `MockBehavior*`, and then dereferences that, yielding a by-reference `MockBehavior` object. This is then presumably returned by value (again the question is missing significant needed context), resulting in a call to the copy constructor of some object type not shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is accessing `COMPOSITE::m_Children[index]`, whatever that is. Hopefully an array of pointers to something.

It then tries to transform that pointer into a pointer to `MockBehavior`. Finally it dereferences that pointer, and returns the result.

If the function containg this is returning by value, that would involve a copy constructor for `MockBehavior`.